# How to set up an environment for android app development?

Tags: android, ide, eclipse, sdk

I have been researching for sometime now regarding the process to install android sdk and associated tools . After visiting [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) page, i first installed the android sdk and then installed eclipse plugins for my indigo version from the install softwares options.However, it is   mentioned in the developers page :

Download the Android SDK.  Install the ADT plugin for Eclipse (if    you’ll use the Eclipse IDE).  Download the latest SDK tools and  platforms using the SDK Manager.

I have downloaded the sdk and installed the adt plugins for eclipse.I just need to point the eclipse towards the location of the sdk.  However, i am stuck at the last step which is asking me to download the latest tools using the sdk manager. The manager interface pops up and i see a lot of options there. I don't know which ones i must select and install. If some one can help me out here and tell me which options to choose and install(if possible, with a screen shot), it will be very beneficial for me.

Comment: I see my question has been down voted by some one. Do kindly tell me , why a question like this which is perennially important to set up a developing environment has been down voted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through setting things up, myself, actually.

For the most part, you'll figure out pretty quickly through trial and error what you'll need. If you're using Eclipse, it will yell at you when you're missing things, and you simply find what you're missing in the SDK Manager and install it.

That said, here's what I needed to get up and running with a very basic setup (this assumes using Android 4.1, if you plan on building for an earlier version, then you'll need to download the corresponding libraries from that version):

- SDK Platform
- ARM EABI v7a System Image (optional, you can also grab the Intel x86 Atom and/or Mips System images if you plan on developing for one of those platforms; ARM is the default, from what I've seen)
- Android SDK Platform-tools

You get these simply by going to the Android SDK Manager (your SDK folder/tools/android; or click the "SDK Manager" button in Eclipse), selecting what you need, and clicking "Install Packages". Once you do that, you can follow the rest of the guide that you linked for building your first app (I highly recommend it, it's extraordinarily beneficial), and your app should run with no problem.

[image: Android SDK Manager]